# CSS media queries - why both min and max-device-height are requested for a specific device and orientation?

Tags: css, iphone, media-queries, screen-size

I trying to define a media query for iPhone 6 portrait only, I found this on SO

```
@media only screen 
    and (min-device-width : 375px) 
    and (max-device-width : 667px) 
    and (orientation : portrait) 
    and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }
```

Why must I define both min-device-width and max-device-width if the orientation is define, why not only a unique fixed device-width ?

Comment: Who said you had to? You could set `min-device-width` to 667, too, I guess?

Comment: Yes, you're true. If I want I can set both min and max device-width to 667 and it works perfectly for what I'm doing.  

But it doesn't response to my question. I still don't get why what seems to be [the standard way](http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/) is to define both min and max

Comment: Because the *general* approach with responsive design is to target whole swaths of resolutions, not very specific single device ones.

Comment: Ok, I get it, just to explain more, I must target the iPhone 6 specifically because of its odd number of pixels.  It's a problem when you try to divide the screen in two parts with the CSS width:50%